# Javascript onMouseMove event syntax

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on some JavaScript code and I run into this syntax that I have never seen and I am trying hard to understand but cannot find good examples.

Can someone please describe what might be going on here?

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    (function(ev) {
       // some piece of code
    })(event);
}
```

Comment: It's an IIFE (Immediately Invoqued Function Expression). Possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is used to create an inner scope using a function and that function is immediately invoked with the event object.

Comment: Of course, we all have to ask why OP would want to do this without having other code that shows us how this makes sense to do, since the `event` argument itself should be sufficient.